# Question of comprehension: Electro-statics, Electro-quasistatics, Displacement current

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-current, gauss-law

Suppose you have a computational model, which is based on:

1. **Boltzmann's equation** (particle solver)

\begin{align}
  \underbrace{\frac{\partial f }{\partial t}}_{a} + \underbrace{\mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla_{\mathbf{x}}\frac{}{}}_{b} f + \underbrace{\frac{\mathbf{F}}{m} \cdot \nabla_{\mathbf{v}}}_{c} f =\underbrace{\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\right|_{\mathrm{Coll}}}_{d},
\end{align}

with the phase space

\begin{align}
  \mathbf{\Omega} = \{\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2,\mathbf{x}_3,\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2,\mathbf{v}_3\},
\end{align}

where $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2,x_3)^{\text{T}}$ and $\mathbf{v}=(v_1,v_2,v_3)^{\text{T}}$ are defined as the particle position and particle velocity, respectively. The first term (a) represents the total temporal change of the one-particle distribution function $f = f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{v},t)$. The second term (b) describes the particle movement. The third term (c) enables interaction with external forces, such as the electromagnetic field via the Lorentz force. The term on the right side (d) is called collision integral and enables the modeling of internal forces, e.g., particle relaxation and chemistry.

2. **Maxwell's equation** (differential, microscopic)

\begin{align}
  \label{eq:Maxwell}
  \nabla\times\mathbf{H}  & = \frac{\partial\mathbf{D}}{\partial t}+\mathbf{j}_{\text{free}},  &(1)\\[0.1em]
  \nabla\times\mathbf{E}  & = - \frac{\partial\mathbf{B}}{\partial t},            & (2)                   \\[0.1em]
  \nabla\cdot\mathbf{D}   & = \rho_{\text{free}}~,    & (3)                                                 \\[0.5em]
  \nabla\cdot\mathbf{B}   & = 0,~ & (4)
\end{align}

Here $\mathbf{D}$ is the electric displacement field, $\mathbf{B}$ the magnetic flux density, $\mathbf{H}$ the magnetic field strength and $\mathbf{E}$ the electric field strength. The influence of electric charges is described by the charge density $\rho_{\text{free}}$ and the current density $\mathbf{j}_{\text{free}}$.

The system is closed by constitutive relations including polarization $\mathbf{P}$ and magnetization $\mathbf{M}$:

**Constitutive relations**

\begin{align}
 \mathbf{D}=\varepsilon_0\mathbf{E}+\mathbf{P}, \quad&\mathbf{B}= \mu_0 \left( \mathbf{H}~+\mathbf{M}\right), & (5)
\end{align}

Moreover, a consistent coupling is needed:

**Two-way coupling**

$$
\begin{aligned}
  \text{Lorentz force:} &&  \frac{\mathbf{F}}{m} &= \frac{q}{m} \left( \mathbf{E} + \mathbf{v}\times \mathbf{B} \right), & (6)\\[0.5em]
  \text{Charge & current density:}&& {{\rho_{\text{free}}}} &= q \int_{\Omega} f d\mathbf{v}, \qquad {{\mathbf{j}_{\text{free}}}} = q \int_{\Omega}\mathbf{v} f d\mathbf{v}. & (7) 
\end{aligned}
$$

---

I am mainly interested in the

**Electrostatic limit**

\begin{align}
\nabla \Phi &= -\mathbf{E}\quad \rightarrow \quad  \nabla\times\mathbf{E}=0~\quad \rightarrow \quad \frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t} = 0~,& (8)
\end{align}

ignoring the magnetic field $\mathbf{B,H}$ as also polarization $\mathbf{P}$  and magnetization $\mathbf{M}$.

The Maxwell equations then can be replaced with the

**Poisson equation**

\begin{align}
  \Delta\Phi&=-\frac{\rho_{\text{free}}}{\varepsilon_{0}}, & (9)
\end{align}

where the coupling reduces to:

**Simplified coupling**

$$
\begin{aligned}
  \text{Lorentz force:} &&  \frac{\mathbf{F}}{m} &= \frac{q}{m}  \mathbf{E} , & (10)\\[0.5em]
  \text{Charge density:}&& {{\rho_{\text{free}}}} &= q \int_{\Omega} f d\mathbf{v}. & (11) 
\end{aligned}
$$

---

To keep it simple, we consider a simple **two-dimensional setup**

[image: Setup]

with **moving positive and negative charged particles**. For the Poisson equation we choose following boundary conditions:

**Field boundary conditions**

$$
\begin{align}
&\Gamma_1:~(\text{Dirichlet})~\Phi = 0, \quad
&\Gamma_{2,3,4}:~(\text{Neumann})~\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial \vec{n}} =0
\end{align}
$$

For the particles solver we choose absorbing boundary condition, meaning that particles are immediately removed when they reach the wall:

**Particle boundary conditions**

$$
\begin{align}
&\Gamma_{1,2,3,4}: \text{Absorbing}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Main question**

Given the simplified model, my goal is to predict a **total electrical current on surface $\Gamma_1$**. The electrical current can be derived via **Gauss law** by integrating the electric current density via

\begin{align}
  \mathbf{I}= -\frac{\mathrm{d} Q}{\mathrm{d} t}~ = -\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t} \int_{\Omega} \rho \operatorname{d}\!\mathbf{V} &= \oint_{\partial\Omega} \mathbf{j} \cdot \operatorname{d}\!\mathbf{S},
\end{align}

The **total electric current density** is defined as sum of displacement and free current via

\begin{align}
  \mathbf{j}_{\mathrm{total}} &:= \varepsilon_0 \frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial t}  + \mathbf{j_{\text{free}}}.
\end{align}

However, due to the simplifications in our electrostatic model in Eq. (10) we know that

\begin{align}
\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{x})=\text{const} = 0,
\end{align}

which results in

\begin{align}
\nabla \times \mathbf{B} = 0.
\end{align}

Moreover, due to Eq. (1) we have

\begin{align}
  \nabla\times\mathbf{H}  & = \frac{\partial\mathbf{D}}{\partial t}+\mathbf{j}_{\text{free}}, \quad | \quad \mathbf{M,P} =0 \\[0.1em] 
\quad \nabla\times\mathbf{B}  & = \varepsilon_0 \frac{\partial\mathbf{E}}{\partial t}+\mathbf{j}_{\text{free}}, \quad | \quad \nabla \times \mathbf{B} = 0 \\[0.1em] 
 \quad 0  & = \varepsilon_0\frac{\partial\mathbf{E}}{\partial t}+\mathbf{j}_{\text{free}}.  \\[0.1em]
\end{align}

This implies that the total current on $\Gamma_1$ is **always zero**:

\begin{align}
  \mathbf{I}_{\mathrm{total}} &= \oint_{\partial\Omega} \mathbf{j}_{\mathrm{total}} \cdot \operatorname{d}\!\mathbf{S},\\
  \mathbf{I}_{\mathrm{total}} &= \oint_{\partial\Omega} 0 \cdot \operatorname{d}\!\mathbf{S},\\
  \mathbf{I}_{\mathrm{total}} &= 0.
\end{align}

**Now my questions are**:

- If one considers a similar three-dimensional setup, does the total current also equal zero?
- Is it even possible to calculate a non-zero current with the simplified model?
- What has to be changed in the evaluation, in order to obtain a non-zero current?
- What has to be changed in the model, to obtain a non-zero current?
- Considering only a part of $\Gamma_1$. What current can be expected here? If the answer is non-zero, how can the current be physically interpreted?

Thanks in advance.